# How to convert an OpenCV cv::Mat to QImage

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, qimage

I am wondering how would I convert the OpenCV C++ standard cv::Mat type to QImage. I have been searching around, but have no luck. I have found some code that converts the IPlimage to QImage, but that is not what I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 47):

Michal Kottman's answer is valid and give expected result for some images but it'll fail on some cases. Here is a solution i found to that problem.

```
QImage imgIn= QImage((uchar*) img.data, img.cols, img.rows, img.step, QImage::Format_RGB888);
```

Difference is adding img.step part. qt won't complain without it but some images won't show properly without it. Hope this will help.

Comment: This is essentially what OpenCV uses internally to convert (http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/repository/revisions/df262b340cbe1b362977573bb34138d837f79648/entry/modules/highgui/src/window_QT.cpp, line 2389) `image2Draw_qt = QImage(image2Draw_mat->data.ptr, image2Draw_mat->cols, image2Draw_mat->rows, image2Draw_mat->step, QImage::Format_RGB888);` Also (approximately, line 2400) `cvConvertImage(mat, image2Draw_mat, CV_CVTIMG_SWAP_RB);` to convert from BGR to RGB.

Comment: `img.step` makes all the difference. I was having weird problems with this conversion, including having the resulting image show distorted and with the wrong colors. Testing a little bit I got the same code.

Answer (score 32):

To convert from `cv::Mat` to `QImage`, you could try to use the `QImage(uchar * data, int width, int height, Format format)` constructor as follows (`mat` is a `cv::Mat`) :

```
QImage img((uchar*)mat.data, mat.cols, mat.rows, QImage::Format_RGB32);
```

It is more efficient than manually converting the pixels to the `QImage`, but you have to keep the original `cv::Mat` image in memory. It can be easily converted to a `QPixmap` and displayed using a `QLabel`:

```
QPixmap pixmap = QPixmap::fromImage(img);
myLabel.setPixmap(pixmap);
```

**Update**

Because OpenCV uses BGR order by default, you should first use `cvtColor(src, dst, CV_BGR2RGB)` to get an image layout that Qt understands.

**Update 2:**

If the image you are trying to show has nonstandard [stride](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stride_of_an_array) (when it is non-continuous, submatrix), the image may appeard distorted. In this case, it is better to explicitly specify the stride using `cv::Mat::step1()`:

```
QImage img((uchar*)mat.data, mat.cols, mat.rows, mat.step1(), QImage::Format_RGB32);
```

Comment: This will not work in the general case. What if mat has >1 channels or data format is not RGB32?

Comment: Well, yes, and it can also have multiple dimensions, or can have different 'step size'. I am expecting that Hien wants to display 'standard' cv::Mat, i.e. loaded by `imread`, or converted to appropriate type.

Comment: @Michael Yes that is what I wanted. I'll try out your code once I have time to work on my project. =)

Comment: opencv uses the BGR channel order.

Comment: You can also convert the qimage to the right RGB order after its been created eg. 

qt_im_rgb = qt_im_bgr.rgbSwapped();

Comment: according to QImage doc: data MUST be 32-bit aligned, so Mat should accomplish this, this is particularly important when Mat type is CV_8UC3, i.e. 24 bit, the @ypnos method below is much more general and safe.

Answer (score 30):

Here is code for 24bit RGB and grayscale floating point. Easily adjustable for other types. It is as efficient as it gets.

```
QImage Mat2QImage(const cv::Mat3b &src) {
        QImage dest(src.cols, src.rows, QImage::Format_ARGB32);
        for (int y = 0; y < src.rows; ++y) {
                const cv::Vec3b *srcrow = src[y];
                QRgb *destrow = (QRgb*)dest.scanLine(y);
                for (int x = 0; x < src.cols; ++x) {
                        destrow[x] = qRgba(srcrow[x][2], srcrow[x][1], srcrow[x][0], 255);
                }
        }
        return dest;
}


QImage Mat2QImage(const cv::Mat_<double> &src)
{
        double scale = 255.0;
        QImage dest(src.cols, src.rows, QImage::Format_ARGB32);
        for (int y = 0; y < src.rows; ++y) {
                const double *srcrow = src[y];
                QRgb *destrow = (QRgb*)dest.scanLine(y);
                for (int x = 0; x < src.cols; ++x) {
                        unsigned int color = srcrow[x] * scale;
                        destrow[x] = qRgba(color, color, color, 255);
                }
        }
        return dest;
}
```

Comment: This answered a question I was about to post about converting floating-point grayscale values into a QImage...thank you!

Comment: this solves the QImage 32 bit alignment requirement when loading from raw data.

Answer (score 14):

OpenCV loads images into a `Mat` in Blue-Green-Red (BGR) format by default, while `QImage` expects RGB. This means that if you convert a `Mat` to `QImage`, the blue and red channels will be swapped. To fix this, before constructing the `QImage`, you need to change the BRG format of your `Mat` to RGB, via the `cvtColor` method using argument `CV_BGR2RGB`, like so:

```
Mat mat = imread("path/to/image.jpg");
cvtColor(mat, mat, CV_BGR2RGB);
QImage image(mat.data, mat.cols, mat.rows, QImage::Format_RGB888);
```

Alternatively, use `rgbSwapped()` on the `QImage`

```
QImage image = QImage(mat.data, mat.cols, mat.rows, QImage::Format_RGB888).rgbSwapped());
```

Answer (score 4):

```
    Mat opencv_image = imread("fruits.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR); 
    Mat dest;
    cvtColor(opencv_image, dest,CV_BGR2RGB);
    QImage image((uchar*)dest.data, dest.cols, dest.rows,QImage::Format_RGB888);
```

This is what worked for me. I modified Michal Kottman's code above.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem as you too, so I develop four functions to alleviate my pain, they are

```
QImage mat_to_qimage_cpy(cv::Mat const &mat, bool swap = true);

QImage mat_to_qimage_ref(cv::Mat &mat, bool swap = true);

cv::Mat qimage_to_mat_cpy(QImage const &img, bool swap = true);

cv::Mat qimage_to_mat_ref(QImage &img, bool swap = true);
```

These functions can handle the images with 1, 3, 4 channels, **every pixel** must occupy **one byte only**(CV_8U->Format_Indexed8, CV_8UC3->QImage::Format_RGB888, CV_8UC4->QImage::Format_ARGB32), I do not deal with other types yet(QImage::Format_RGB16, QImage::Format_RGB666 and so on). The codes are located
at [github](https://github.com/stereomatchingkiss/ocv_libs/blob/master/qt/mat_and_qimage.cpp).

The **key concepts** of **transform mat to Qimage ** are

```
/**
 * @brief copy QImage into cv::Mat
 */
struct mat_to_qimage_cpy_policy
{
    static QImage start(cv::Mat const &mat, QImage::Format format)
    {
       //The fourth parameters--mat.step is crucial, because 
       //opencv may do padding on every row, you need to tell
       //the qimage how many bytes per row 
       //The last thing is if you want to copy the buffer of cv::Mat
       //to the qimage, you need to call copy(), else the qimage
       //will share the buffer of cv::Mat
       return QImage(mat.data, mat.cols, mat.rows, mat.step, format).copy();
    }
};

struct mat_to_qimage_ref_policy
{
    static QImage start(cv::Mat &mat, QImage::Format format)
    {
       //every thing are same as copy policy, but this one share
       //the buffer of cv::Mat but not copy
       return QImage(mat.data, mat.cols, mat.rows, mat.step, format);
    }
};
```

The **key concepts** of transform `cv::Mat to Qimage` are

```
/**
 * @brief copy QImage into cv::Mat
 */
struct qimage_to_mat_cpy_policy
{
    static cv::Mat start(QImage const &img, int format)
    {
       //same as convert mat to qimage, the fifth parameter bytesPerLine()
       //indicate how many bytes per row
       //If you want to copy the data you need to call clone(), else QImage
       //cv::Mat will share the buffer
       return cv::Mat(img.height(), img.width(), format, 
                      const_cast<uchar*>(img.bits()), img.bytesPerLine()).clone();
    }
};

/**
 * @brief make Qimage and cv::Mat share the same buffer, the resource
 * of the cv::Mat must not deleted before the QImage finish
 * the jobs.
 */
struct qimage_to_mat_ref_policy
{
    static cv::Mat start(QImage &img, int format)
    {
       //same as copy policy, but this one will share the buffer 
       return cv::Mat(img.height(), img.width(), format, 
                      img.bits(), img.bytesPerLine());
    }
};
```

If would be good if some one can extend these functions and make them support more types, please inform me if there are any bugs.

Answer (score 2):

cv::Mat has a conversion operator to IplImage, so if you have something that converts the IplImage to a QImage, just use that (or make the - probably minor - adjustments to take the cv::Mat directly, the memory layout is the same, it's "just" the header that is different.)

Comment: The project that I am working on requires me to print out the image onto the QtGui, but I will be working on the images in cv::Mat most of the time. The reason I am asking is that my program will do a lot of computation so I want to get rid of the overhead of converting cv::Mat to IplImage and then to qimage. This is my first image processing project so I don't really know much about the data that are in an image. I will learn about this soon enough once I dive more into the project. Anyway, if I can't find anything, then I'll follow your suggestion =)

Comment: Can you please share the code for IplImage -> QImage conversion? I am interested to make the needed adjustments to convert it to cv::Mat.

Comment: @Hien: The overhead of the conversion cv::Mat to IplImage is, compared to all the other stuff you do when doing image processing, completely negligible. There is no copying of data involved.

Answer (score 2):

[This post](http://umanga.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/how-to-covert-qt-qimage-into-opencv-iplimage-and-wise-versa/) shows how to convert a `QImage` to OpenCV's `IplImage` and vise-versa.

After that, if you need help to convert between `IplImage*` to `cv::Mat`:

```
// Assume data is stored by: 
// IplImage* image;

cv::Mat mat(image, true); // Copies the data from image

cv::Mat mat(image, false); // Doesn't copy the data!
```

It's a hack, but will get the job done.

Answer (score 1):

Use the static function convert16uc1 for the depth image:

```
QPixmap Viewer::convert16uc1(const cv::Mat& source)
{
  quint16* pSource = (quint16*) source.data;
  int pixelCounts = source.cols * source.rows;

  QImage dest(source.cols, source.rows, QImage::Format_RGB32);

  char* pDest = (char*) dest.bits();

  for (int i = 0; i < pixelCounts; i++)
  {
    quint8 value = (quint8) ((*(pSource)) >> 8);
    *(pDest++) = value;  // B
    *(pDest++) = value;  // G
    *(pDest++) = value;  // R
    *(pDest++) = 0;      // Alpha
    pSource++;
  }

  return QPixmap::fromImage(dest);
}

QPixmap Viewer::convert8uc3(const cv::Mat& source)
{
  quint8* pSource = source.data;
  int pixelCounts = source.cols * source.rows;

  QImage dest(source.cols, source.rows, QImage::Format_RGB32);

  char* pDest = (char*) dest.bits();

  for (int i = 0; i < pixelCounts; i++)
  {
    *(pDest++) = *(pSource+2);    // B
    *(pDest++) = *(pSource+1);    // G
    *(pDest++) = *(pSource+0);    // R
    *(pDest++) = 0;               // Alpha
    pSource+=3;
  }

  return QPixmap::fromImage(dest);
}

QPixmap Viewer::convert16uc3(const cv::Mat& source)
{
  quint16* pSource = (quint16*) source.data;
  int pixelCounts = source.cols * source.rows;

  QImage dest(source.cols, source.rows, QImage::Format_RGB32);

  char* pDest = (char*) dest.bits();

  for (int i = 0; i < pixelCounts; i++)
  {
    *(pDest++) = *(pSource+2);    // B
    *(pDest++) = *(pSource+1);    // G
    *(pDest++) = *(pSource+0);    // R
    *(pDest++) = 0;               // Alpha
    pSource+=3;
  }

  return QPixmap::fromImage(dest);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to re-use the data-pointer of the mat instead of copying all the data, you can use the following code:

```cpp
cv::Mat mat // defined elsewhere

QImage image(mat.data, mat.cols, mat.rows, QImage::Format_YOUR_FORMAT);

mat.deallocate(); // <-- this 'removes' the pointer from mat
```

We use the `cv::Mat::deallocate` function, which leads to the `cv::Mat` not deleting the underlying data when it's deleted.

So if you save your `QImage` as a class-member or return it from a function, you'd have to normally copy the data from the `Mat` since after the stack ends, it would delete the array in the back.

Deallocate kind of "removes" the pointer from the `Mat` so it doesn't delete the data that we assigned the `QImage` (since otherwise the `QImage` would point to freed-up memory).

Answer (score -4):

This did the trick for me. It's a little dodgy, has terrible performance (as pointed out in the comments), but works with all color formats I have thrown at it so far, and it is also very simple to do.

The procedure is as follows:

```
cv::Mat image = //...some image you want to display

// 1. Save the cv::Mat to some temporary file
cv::imwrite("../Images/tmp.jpg",image);

// 2. Load the image you just saved as a QImage
QImage img;
img.load("../Images/tmp.jpg");
```

**Done!**

If you, say, want to display it in a QLabel, then continue with:

```
// Set QImage as content of MyImageQLabel
ui-> MyImageQLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(img, Qt::AutoColor));
```

I personally use this for a simple image editor.

Comment: @AxeEffect This is certainly not a high performing solution, considering you have to do read/write operation towards the HDD. For some usages, though, that doesn't really matter. :-)