# QImage and QPixmap image display incorrect

Tags: qt, opencv, qpixmap

I am running OpenCV with QT on Ubuntu and have hit a problem with displaying an image using a QLabel.
If I use the code:( where 'image' is a Mat created by dcraw):

```
Mat img_display;

cv::cvtColor(image,img_display,CV_BGR2RGB); 

imwrite("test.jpg",img_display);

QImage img=QImage("test.jpg");  // QImage assignment

QPixmap pixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(img));

widget.image_label->setPixmap(pixmap);
```

The image is output in colour and exactly as I would expect.

However, when I replace the QImage assignment to use 'img_display' rather than the .jpg file, my image display starts to the right of the origin and has a triangle  overwriting the bottom right of the displayed image.  This triangle looks like it is half of the missing bit from the LHS of the image. The assignment code I am trying to use is:

```
QImage img=QImage(
    (uchar*)(img_display.data),
    img_display.cols,
    img_display.rows,
    QImage::Format_RGB888);
```

image comes from a raw 18.2mb cr2 file and it was created by dcraw. test.jpg is 3.1mb

Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: As well as being distorted, the image output is in black and white.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to convert an opencv cv::Mat to qimage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026965/how-to-convert-an-opencv-cvmat-to-qimage)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I had seen that answer but didn't think it was relevant to my problem.  I implemented the Mat2QImage as suggested  with the image type RGB888 and the corruption went away.  The image is  still black and white, so I need a format other than RGB888 (?). I obviously need to understand the conversion process more.  Thanks again.