# Convert Mat to QPixmap

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, opencv, qpixmap

How can we convert directly cv::Mat to QPixmap without going through filename loading?

I have made some research about it but no hints!

As a first step, what I have tried is that I save the image, and then load it. But it's not what I want to have.

Comment: You could probably use the function `QPixmap::loadFromData(...)`  to load the field `cv::Mat::data` directly into the `QPixmap`. I never tried to do such a thing though.

Comment: And by the way, [possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026965/how-to-convert-an-opencv-cvmat-to-qimage) since it's easy to switch between Qimage and QPixmap.

Comment: And how to switch between QImage and QPixmap?

Comment: Cannot be easier: `QPixmap::fromImage()`.

Answer (score 13):

Jehan is right.

For people referring to this thread in the future:
First convert image from BGR(used by OpenCV) to RGB.

Then:

```
QPixmap::fromImage(QImage((unsigned char*) mat.data, mat.cols, mat.rows, QImage::Format_RGB888));
```

Comment: You can also use QPixmap::fromImage(QImage((unsigned char*) mat.data, mat.cols, mat.rows, QImage::Format_RGB888).rgbswapped()); so you dont have to convert image before starting

Comment: This isn't working for Mat3b. What exactly could be the reason?

Comment: QPixmap pix= QPixmap::fromImage(QImage((unsigned char*) img.data, img.cols, img.rows, QImage::Format_RGB888).rgbSwapped());

     ui->mylable->setPixmap(pix);

Comment: After Qt 5.14 there is a new QImage format [`QImage::Format_BGR888`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#Format-enum) so a better method is to specify the format as `QImage::Format_BGR888` and no need to convert colors now.

Answer (score 3):

Mehfoos Yacoob is right, that is the best way to convert a `cv::Mat` to a `QPixmap`. First, you need to convert the `cv::Mat` to a `QImage`, and then using the `fromImage` function, assign its result to a `QPixmap`. It is important to keep in mind the type of the `cv::Mat` in order to use the correct `QImage` format.

This is a little example of how to do it: http://asmaloney.com/2013/11/code/converting-between-cvmat-and-qimage-or-qpixmap/

Comment: as additional information to this solution (as told in http://stackoverflow.com/a/12312326/2590275) is that "some images won't show properly without it." -> add the mat.step as 4th parameter.
The example linked  above to [asmaloney](http://asmaloney.com/2013/11/code/converting-between-cvmat-and-qimage-or-qpixmap/) also includes that parameter it his calls.