# cv::Mat to QImage convertion not working properly

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, qt4, qimage

I'm working with `opencv` and I have to integrate it to a `Qt` Gui, but I have some issue for showing the image in `Qt` ...

Here is the code that I'm using

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtGui>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

QImage const Mat2QImage(const cv::Mat& src){
  return QImage((unsigned char*)src.data, src.cols, src.rows, src.step, QImage::Format_RGB888);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){

  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  cv::Mat src = cv::imread("lena.jpg");

  QLabel aLabel;
  QImage img = Mat2QImage(src);
  aLabel.resize(src.rows, src.cols);
  aLabel.setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(img));
  aLabel.show();

  return app.exec();

}
```

And Here is the result : 
[image]

Note that if I change the format to `QImage::FormatRGB32` I will get an empty window, I've also tried all the formats and that wasn't what I'm expacting ...
Any idea about how to solve the issue ?

Thanks !

Comment: well OpenCV uses this BGR thing and QT uses RGB, I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026965/how-to-convert-an-opencv-cvmat-to-qimage will help you out ( espec calling `cvtColor(src, dst, CV_BGR2RGB)` before your Mat2QImage call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCV saves the image in bgr format. This means the color values of the pixels are swapped.
If you add this line to your program the image gets displayed correctly:

```
  img = img.rgbSwapped();
```