# how to convert back QImage to cv::Mat

Tags: opencv, qt5

I have graped an image from videoCapture object then i converted it to QImage to send it to server. After i receive it from the server side i want to do some image processing on the received image which is QImage. So before i performing any processing i have to convert it back to cv::Mat image.

I have function converting cv::Mat to QImage

```
    // Copy input Mat
    const uchar *qImageBuffer = (const uchar*)mat.data;
    // Create QImage with same dimensions as input Mat
    QImage img(qImageBuffer, mat.cols, mat.rows, mat.step, QImage::Format_RGB888);
    //en
    img.bits();
    return img.rgbSwapped();
```

have function converting QImage to cv::Mat

```
Mat QImageToMat(const QImage& src){

cv::Mat tmp(src.height(),src.width(),CV_8UC3,(uchar*)src.bits(),src.bytesPerLine());

cv::Mat result = tmp ; // deep copy just in case (my lack of knowledge with open cv)

for (int i=0;i<src.height();i++) {
    memcpy(result.ptr(i),src.scanLine(i),src.bytesPerLine());
}
cvtColor(result, result,CV_RGB2BGR);


return result;
```

}

I have been searching for about 2 days how to convert QImage to cv::Mat but with no luck non of the code snippet works for me. I don't know why, the image after conversion looks bad. you can see the image to left.

Does someone have any idea, about what could be cause the problem? Thanks in advance.

[image]

LEFT:image after converted from QImage to Mat RIGHT: the origranl Image which is in QImage format

Comment: have you tried 12 bit instead of 8 bit image?

Comment: No i didn't. the orginal image is from my webcam how can i set the image to be 12 bit?

Comment: check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026965/how-to-convert-an-opencv-cvmat-to-qimage

Comment: You got any correct answers ???

Comment: Im having same problem