# How to convert ROI from/to QImage to/from cv::Mat?

Tags: opencv, qimage, roi

I cannot properly convert and/or display an ROI using a QRect in a QImage and create  a cv::Mat image out of the QImage. 
The problem is symmetric, i.e, I cannot properly get the ROI by using a cv::Rect in a cv::Mat and creating a QImage out of the Mat. Surprisingly, everything work fine whenever the width and the height of the cv::Rect or the QRect are equal.

In what follows, my full-size image is the cv::Mat matImage. It is of type `CV_8U` and has a square size of 2048x2048

```
int x = 614;
int y = 1156;

// buggy
int width = 234;
int height = 278;

//working
//    int width = 400;
//    int height = 400;
QRect ROI(x, y, width, height);

QImage imageInit(matImage.data, matImage.cols, matImage.rows,   QImage::Format_Grayscale8);
QImage imageROI = imageInit.copy(ROI);
createNewImage(imageROI);

unsigned char* dataBuffer = imageROI.bits();
cv::Mat tempImage(cv::Size(imageROI.width(), imageROI.height()), CV_8UC1, dataBuffer, cv::Mat::AUTO_STEP);

cv::namedWindow( "openCV imshow() from a cv::Mat image", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
cv::imshow( "openCV imshow() from a cv::Mat image", tempImage);
```

The screenshot below illustrates the issue.

[image: full size and ROI]
(Left) The full-size `cv::Mat matImage`.
(Middle) the expected result from the `QImage` and the `QRect` (which roughly corresponds to the green rectangle drawn by hand). 
(Right) the messed-up result from the `cv::Mat matImageROI`

Comment: I'm using Qt 5.6 and openCV 3.1 , Mac OS X 10.10.5, Macbook Pro Retina.

Answer (score 0):

By exploring other issues regarding conversion between `cv::Mat` and `QImage`, it seems the stride becomes "non-standard" in some particular ROI sizes. For example, from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026965/how-to-convert-an-opencv-cvmat-to-qimage?rq=1), I found out one just needs to change `cv::Mat::AUTO_STEP` to `imageROI.bytesPerLine()` in
`cv::Mat tempImage(cv::Size(imageROI.width(), imageROI.height()), CV_8UC1, dataBuffer, cv::Mat::AUTO_STEP);`

so I end up instead with: 
`cv::Mat matImageROI(cv::Size(imageROI.width(), imageROI.height()), CV_8UC1, dataBuffer, imageROI.bytesPerLine());`

For the other way round, i.e, creating the QImage from a ROI of a cv::Mat, one would use the property `cv::Mat::step`.

For example:

`QImage imageROI(matImageROI.data, matImageROI.cols, matImageROI.rows, matImageROI.step, QImage::Format_Grayscale8);`

instead of:

`QImage imageROI(matImageROI.data, matImageROI.cols, matImageROI.rows, QImage::Format_Grayscale8);`

**Update**

For the case of odd ROI sizes, although it is not a problem when using either `imshow()` with `cv::Mat` or `QImage` in `QGraphicsScene`, it becomes an issue when using openGL (with `QOpenGLWidget`). I guess the simplest workaround is just to constrain ROIs to have even sizes.