# Transform a YUV420p QVideoFrame into grayscale OpenCV mat

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, yuv, qtmultimedia

I've created a filter extending `QAbstractVideoFilter` and 
`QVideoFilterRunnable` and I've overrided the

```
QVideoFrame run(QVideoFrame* input, const QVideoSurfaceFormat &surfaceFormat, RunFlags flags)`
```

method

The problem is that `QVideoFrame` format is `Format_YUV420P` and has no handle. I need to convert it into a `CV_8UC1` in order to use `OpenCV` algorithms.

Which is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026965/how-to-convert-an-opencv-cvmat-to-qimage) for a possible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to create a `cv::Mat` which has an [API](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#Mat::Mat(int%20rows,%20int%20cols,%20int%20type,%20void*%20data,%20size_t%20step)) for initializing using data pointer as:

```
cv::Mat img = cv::Mat(rows, cols, CV_8UC3, input.data/*Change this to point the first element of array containing the YUV color info*/)
```

Now since the `img` is initialized with YUV color data, you may use various `cvtColor` modes to convert the YUV mat to other formats, for converting it to gray-scale you may try:

```
cv::Mat gray;
cv::cvtColor(img, gray, cv::COLOR_YUV2GRAY_I420);
```

Comment: Y'420P is ordered the first half of data is the lumia (look at this pic https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Yuv420.svg in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV) so a simple solution is to copy only the first half of data `cv::Mat mat(height, width, CV_8UC1, data);`

Comment: Yeah it would serve the purpose if you want to convert the img to gray-scale only, but what if someone wants to convert to RGB, I tried to put up a generic answer, However your approach is more optimised :)