# problem on displaying live video in qt c++ application

Tags: c++, qt, raspberry-pi, live-streaming, live-video

I want to show a live stream of the camera connected to raspberry in qt application (OS Linux). After googling it, I found out I must display the video inside QLabel. When displaying an image there's no problem and everything works fine, but when I want to display the live stream inside QLabel, the live stream window opens separately (not inside QLabel). would you tell me how to solve this problem? here's my code :

```
void Dialog::on_Preview_clicked()
{
    command = "raspistill";
    args<<"-o"<<"/home/pi/Pictures/Preview/"+Date1.currentDateTime().toString()+".jpg"<<"-t"<<QString::number(20000);
    Pic.start(command,args,QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    QPixmap pix("//home//pi//Pictures//Preview//test.jpg");
    ui->label_2->setPixmap(pix);
    ui->label_2->setScaledContents(true);
}
```

This code opens video capturing screen and captures an image after 20 seconds. the only problem is that the capture screen (which could be used as a live stream). isn't being displayed inside the "Lable_2". Is there anyway to do this without using OpenCV library? If not, tell me how to do it using OpenCV.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Stream the camera using `OpenCV`, and show it in `QLabel` is possible.
When QCamera not working, and also use OpenCV in the project, could use `VideoCapture` to stream the video instead of QCamera.

The problem can be decomposed into several steps. Basically, We need:

1. Create a `QThread` for streaming(Don't let the GUI thread blocked).
2. In the sub-thread, using `cv::VideoCapture` to capture the frame into a `cv::Mat`.
3. Convert the `cv::Mat` to `QImage`([how to convert an opencv cv::Mat to qimage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026965/how-to-convert-an-opencv-cvmat-to-qimage)).
4. Pass `QImage` frame from sub-thread to the main GUI thread.
5. Paint the `QImage` on the `QLabel`.

I put the complete demo code in [Github](https://github.com/arkceajin/QtDemos/tree/master/QtOpenCVCam). it could paint the frame on the `QLabel` and QML `VideoOutput`.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty simple in opencv

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

 int main( int argc, char** argv )
 {
        VideoCapture cap(0); // open the default camera
    if(!cap.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
        return -1;

    Mat edges;
    namedWindow("edges",1);
    for(;;)
    {
        Mat frame;

        cap >> frame; // get a new frame from camera

        imshow("edges", frame);
        if(waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the respond. then how can I set the live stream window on a QLable?