# QVideoWidget doesn't display frames

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, video-capture

I created a subclass of `QVideoWidget` in order to display Video Frames from a camera (Basler, Pylon C++ API). Briefly, frames are converted to `cv::Mat` and then analyzed by a Neural Network. After that, I subclassed a `QAbstractVideoSurface` that presents frame to the VideoWidget.

When I try to display my frame in the QVideoWidget, the function `void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)` is triggered by `update()` or `repaint()`, but nothing is displayed on the widget. What's wrong?

I checked from the beginning of the pipeline, to the end, everything is OK (the frame contains data, the pixel format is OK, size OK, I can save a video file with actual frames in it, *etc*). I can see the widget in UI. I really suspect my paintEvent function.

Here is my paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) function:

```
// VideoWidget.h

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) override;
```

```
// VideoWidget.cpp

void VideoWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) {
    QPainter p(this);
    p.drawImage(QRectF(m_targetRect), m_frameConv);
    QVideoWidget::paintEvent(event);
}
```

PS: I'm on MacOS 11 (it didn't work neither on MacOSX), I'm using CMake 3.17.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to subclass `QVideoWidget` for this. Convert [frame to image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026965/how-to-convert-an-opencv-cvmat-to-qimage) and present it on `QVideoWidget::videoSurface()` like documentation says

```
videoWidget = new QVideoWidget;
QVideoSurfaceFormat format(imgSize, QVideoFrame::Format_ARGB32);
videoWidget->videoSurface()->start(format);

QImage img = frameToImage(m_frameConv).convertToFormat(QImage::Format_ARGB32);
videoWidget->videoSurface()->present(img);
videoWidget->show();
```

Comment: Hi, it makes things easier, but the frame is still not displayed. But that's a great improvement in a way.

Comment: When I put `m_videoWidget->videoSurface()->present(frame);` in a slot, `m_videoWidget->videoSurface()->error()`  gives me: `StoppedError`. I start the surface before. Do we agree that I need to call `present()` each time a new frame had been grabbed?